# How to automate xcode clean process using fastlane Fastfile lane

Tags: xcode, fastlane, fastfile

I am looking for a way to automate xcode clean process using fastlate.

What I am looking to achieve:

1. Clear Derived Data Folder
2. Clean build folder
3. Clean
4. Build

So far I automated the derived data folder

```
lane :clean do
  clear_derived_data
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have achieve 1,2 and 3, but for 4, you need to use Gym
It's easy to use, follow his guide
https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/gym/

```
lane :cleanAndBuild do
  clear_derived_data
  gym( my_params )
end
```